# How do I make product column width in Volusion span the entire screen for mobile and have products stack?

Tags: volusion

Trying to make product column width in Volusion span the entire screen for mobile and have products stack below. I am working out of this site: http://enpgp.fzsvf.servertrust.com/category-s/100.htm and you can see on mobile the products simple cram together as opposed to stacking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to each category that you want to be responsive and select in the category display mode dropdown menu "Responsive Grid".

If that option for some reason is not shown you can force the category into "responsive mode" by changing one of the options in the "Product Display Mode" to "7" and then select it and click the save button. You would do that with Firebug. You could also import a "7" into "Product Display Mode" for that category via the API.

```
<select name="Category_DisplayMode" onblur="ProcessFieldUsage(this);" onkeyup="ShowSave()" onchange="ShowSave()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Single Rows</option>
    <option value="2">Grid</option>
    <option value="4">Checkboxes</option>
    <option value="5">List</option>
    <option value="6">Lightweight Grid</option>
 </select>
```

Shown after the modification

```
<select name="Category_DisplayMode" onblur="ProcessFieldUsage(this);" onkeyup="ShowSave()" onchange="ShowSave()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Single Rows</option>
    <option value="2">Grid</option>
    <option value="4">Checkboxes</option>
    <option value="5">List</option>
    <option value="7">Lightweight Grid</option>
 </select>
```